# How do I create a Quill editor without a toolbar?

Tags: javascript, quill

I would like to use Quill but not display an editor toolbar (or the "bubble" alternative). I would essentially like a text area with Quill/Parchment backing it.

However, whenever I create a new Quill element, I always get the toolbar, even though I don't ask for it. Additionally, removing the toolbar causes a JavaScript error, which breaks anything else running on the page.

The default:

```js
var config = {
  "theme": "snow"
};

var quill = new Quill( ".editor", config );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="editor"></div>
```

Setting modules to an empty object is the same (I believe this is the default anyway):

```js
var config = {
  "theme": "snow",
  "modules": {}
};

var quill = new Quill( ".editor", config );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="editor"></div>
```

Setting the toolbar module to either `false` or `null` results in a JavaScript error:

```js
var config = {
  "theme": "snow",
  "modules": {
      "toolbar": false
  }
};

var quill = new Quill( ".editor", config );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="editor"></div>
```

```js
var config = {
  "theme": "snow",
  "modules": {
      "toolbar": null
  }
};

var quill = new Quill( ".editor", config );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="editor"></div>
```

Here's what I want, but this seems like a hacky workaround and I don't like it:

```js
var config = {
  "theme": "snow",
  "modules": {
    "toolbar": ".quill-always-hidden-toolbar"
  }
};

var quill = new Quill( ".editor", config );
```

```css
.quill-always-hidden-toolbar{
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.quill-always-hidden-toolbar.ql-toolbar.ql-snow + .ql-container.ql-snow{
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.js"></script>

<div class="quill-always-hidden-toolbar"></div>
<div class="editor"></div>
```

It appears there's no way to *not* have a toolbar on a Quill editor short of rendering it into a DOM node that is always `display: none`. Is this true, or **is there another more graceful way of not rendering the toolbar?**

tl;dr: I don't want the Quill Toolbar, how do I create a new Quill instance without the toolbar?

(You can play with these different config options yourself at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/8t9vuxL1/))

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A falsy value for toolbar should be correct:

```
var config = {
  "theme": "snow",
  "modules": {
      "toolbar": false
  }
};
```

Here's a [bug report](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/955) for tracking.

Comment: Fixed as of Quill 1.0.4. Thanks for keeping tabs on SO!

Comment: I'm still getting this issue, don't know why

Answer (score 10):

You can set theme `bubble` to show medium-like editor instead of always visible version;

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'bubble'   // Specify theme in configuration
});
```

[Examples](https://quilljs.com/docs/themes/) (both bubble and snow (default) themes)

Answer (score 3):

You can take two different approaches. 
The first one is just pass in the options a false value.

```
var config = {
  modules: {
      toolbar: false,
      syntax: true
  },
  "theme": "snow",
};
```

On the other hand you could also use a prefix theme that comes with no toolbar at all.

```
var config = {
  "theme": "bubble",
};
```

All the text editors I used have a prefix theme where there is no toolbar available.